# Error while starting webpack dev server over nodejs fastify

Tags: node.js, webpack, apollo, autoload, fastify

command:

```
"build": "webpack --config ./webpack.development.js"
"start": "fastify start -l debug --options dist/bundle.js",
```

error:

```
    AvvioError \[Error\]: Plugin must be a function or a promise. Received: 'object'
    at assertPlugin (C:\\Local\\Work\\Digital\\yyy\\DEV\\GIT\\yyy-webpack\\node_modules\\avvio\\boot.js:207:11)
    at Boot.\_addPlugin (C:\\Local\\Work\\Digital\\yyy\\DEV\\GIT\\yyy-webpack\\node_modules\\avvio\\boot.js:240:12)
    at Boot.use (C:\\Local\\Work\\Digital\\yyy\\DEV\\GIT\\yyy-webpack\\node_modules\\avvio\\boot.js:216:25)
    at Object.server.\<computed\> \[as register\] (C:\\Local\\Work\\Digital\\yyy\\DEV\\GIT\\yyy-webpack\\node_modules\\avvio\\boot.js:40:14)
    at runFastify (C:\\Local\\Work\\Digital\\yyy\\DEV\\GIT\\yyy-webpack\\node_modules\\fastify-cli\\start.js:149:17) {
    code: 'AVV_ERR_PLUGIN_NOT_VALID'
    }
```

How can i debug the fastify autoload plugin?

tried to debug setting fastify start command -l option didnt work..
expectation is to start application successfully with one bundle.js file and serve graphql apollo playground

Update: ./webpack.development.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge.smart(common, {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000', path.join(__dirname, 'src/app.ts')],
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
        allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000']
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
  },
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
});
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  target: 'node'
};
```

Fastify autoload:

```
    await fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
        dir: join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
        options: opts,
    })
```

Comment: What does the bundle exports?

Comment: Please show your `./webpack.development.js"`

Comment: updated with development config